# How can sharing screen with socket in web page?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I have a javascript code to share the screen and I need to convert this code to socket.How can I do that?

```
 <script>
    async function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {

      let captureStream = null;

      try {
        captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
        document.getElementsByClassName('screen-btn')[0].classList.toggle("toggle-icons");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: " + err);
      }

      return captureStream;

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: are you using nodejs?

Comment: @Kashif python for server side.